# PHP CRYPT_BLOWFISH Error?

Tags: php, pear, mcrypt, blowfish

I'm on Redhat and using PHP `Crypt_Blowfish` and having following error.

ERROR:

> Notice: Constant CRYPT_BLOWFISH_AUTO already defined in /usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish.php on line 33 Notice: Constant CRYPT_BLOWFISH_MCRYPT already defined in /usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish.php on line 38 Notice: Constant CRYPT_BLOWFISH_PHP already defined in /usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish.php on line 43 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Crypt_Blowfish in /usr/share/pear/Crypt/Blowfish.php on line 88

My code is just something like:

```
include_once('Blowfish.php');
$key = '12345678';
$cipher = new Crypt_Blowfish($key);
echo Eencrypt($cipher, "hello world!");
```

And when i check my `php.ini`, the `mcrypt` is also already installed and enabled.

[image]

- What went seriously wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Strict standards warnings are *no* errors. You can remove them from your error_reporting setting easily:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_STRICT);
```